# Inversion formula in a paper of Prof. Siegmund about "one sided stopping rule"

Tags: inverse, stopping-times

I am reading a [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177698129) about one sided stopping rule. On the 2nd page and line 16-17, the author has that $\lambda=(c/\mu)^{1/(1-\alpha)}$ and the author lets $x$ be arbitrary and assume that $n$ is a function of $c$ such that
$$[cn^\alpha-n\mu](\sigma n^{\frac{1}{2}})^{-1}=-x,\tag{1}$$
then the author says that so by inversion, we have
$$[n-\lambda][(1-\alpha)^{-1}\lambda^{0.5}\mu^{-1}\sigma]^{-1}\rightarrow x.\tag{2}$$

My question is that how does the author derives the (2) equation using (1) ? Can anyone share some insights and what is the meaning of $\rightarrow$ which the author did not define this symbol before? Thank you (It should be easy but I am confused here)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot energy on proving this, I find out that there is a lot of details left over to reader in this paper. Later on I find another paper by Allan Gut who explains this issue clearly. For details see ["On the moments and limit distributions of some first passage times" By Allan Gut.](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176996709)